# Remove one directory component from path (string manipulation)

Tags: bash, tcsh

I'm looking for the easiest and most readable way to remove a field from a path. So for example, I have /this/is/my/complicated/path/here, and I would like to remove the 5th field ("/complicated") from the string, using bash commands, so that it becomes /this/is/my/path.
I could do this with

```
echo "/this/is/my/complicated/path/here" | cut -d/ -f-4
echo "/"
echo "/this/is/my/complicated/path/here" | cut -d/ -f6-
```

but I would like this done in just one easy command, something that would like

```
echo "/this/is/my/complicated/path" | tee >(cut -d/ -f-4) >(cut -d/ -f6-)
```

except that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `cut`, you can specify a comma separated list of fields to print:

```
$ echo "/this/is/my/complicated/path/here" | cut -d/ -f-4,6-
/this/is/my/path/here
```

So, it's not really necessary to use two commands.

Comment: Thank you. this solves my problem. However, I'm curious: is it possible to feed the result of one command to two commands ?

Comment: You can sort of do it like this: `echo hello | tee >(sed 's/l/L/g') | sed 's/h/H/g'` but note that the output from the first `sed` will also pass through the second sed, or like in your original post `echo hello | tee >(sed 's/l/L/g') >(sed 's/h/H/g')` but then you get three copies.

Comment: Hmmm, you can avoid passing the output of one through the other like this `echo hello | tee >(sed 's/l/L/g' > /dev/tty) | sed 's/h/H/g'` but that only works in a terminal session, of course, otherwise you'd need your own named pipe, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

How about using sed?

```bsh
$ echo "/this/is/my/complicated/path/here" | sed -e "s%complicated/%%"
/this/is/my/path/here
```

Comment: In my script, I do not know the value of the fifth field, I just know it is the fifth.

Answer (score 0):

This removes the 5th path element

```
echo "/this/is/my/complicated/path/here" | 
  perl -F/ -lane 'splice @F,4,1; print join("/", @F)'
```

just bash

```
IFS=/ read -a dirs <<< "/this/is/my/complicated/path/here"
newpath=$(IFS=/; echo "${dirs[*]:0:4} ${dirs[*]:5}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with a bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash        

if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
    us=$(echo $0 | sed "s/^\.\///") # Get rid of a starting ./
    echo "        "Usage: $us StringToParse [delimiterChar] [start] [end]
    echo StringToParse: string to remove something from. Required
    echo delimiterChar: Character to mark the columns "(default '/')"
    echo "        "start: starting column to cut "(default 5)"
    echo "          "end: last column to cut "(default 5)"
    exit
fi


# Parse the parameters
theString=$1
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    delim=/
    start=4
    end=6
else
    delim=$2
    if [ -z "$3" ]; then
        start=4
        end=6
    else
        start=`expr $3 - 1`
        if [ -z "$4" ]; then
            end=6
        else
            end=`expr $4 + 1`
        fi
    fi
fi

result=`echo $theString | cut -d$delim -f-$start`
result=$result$delim
final=`echo $theString | cut -d$delim -f$end-`
result=$result$final
echo $result
```